# what is more important speed(time) or space

Tags: performance, diskspace, benchmarking

I had this question when I was given a task which made me think for a while. But not able to come up with more accurate or satisfying answer.
The task was something like this,
**Things I already have**

- a table "User" which contain details about the user. Like createdTime, type(agent, admin, other), id, etc.,(This table contains too many rows(entries) in it)

**The task given to me is**

- create a new table which will keep track of user which are deleted.
- Then join the "User" table with this newly created table and show the user which are not already deleted and are of type='agent'.

**Now my question is**

- "why are they asking me to create a new table instead of creating a new column(in User table) which will store a flag(true If user is deleted, else not deleted)
- "Is join not time consuming?"
- (creating a new column in the current "User" table will help in keeping the detail intact with the User.But creating a new table - where this will help?)

When I asked this question to my team member, he replied *"If you create a new column, the value can be empty for a lot of rows, and space wastage"* (what he said is right too.)

This states that he is caring about the space more and less on query time.

Nowadays we can get any amount of space with money, But speed is more important right. If the speed is less, then what is the use of anything which saves our disk space.

Shouldn't we care about time more and space less?.

I would like to know what you think about this. What is more important to you and why?.

I know this question can be down-voted But I wanted to know what most developers think in such case. What they care about more is it space or time?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

*This will be an answer even though it's personally speaking because it's too big for a comment:*

The two are rarely separate from each other but a function of each other.

Speed is also not just 'query time' - but basically execution time including data handling. From request to reply.
So if you have something that hogs space, you have more I/O and more memory usage and need to spend more time accessing data and more time transmitting data. 
So my "answer" would be:
*Treat both as equal and minimize both.*

**This states that he is caring about the space more and less on query time. :**
No. That's a wrong assumption.

If you start thinking normalization and de-normalization in the database when thinking performance, you are most always better off normalizing data.
This is not only to save space, but also to save maintenance of data/data integrity (faster update, less locking); Indexing (space, yes - but also speed) and then when using the data I/O transfer from disk to server, to memory usage, across networks. Also - space usage means memory usage and the more things take up space, the more you want to also put into memory.

All these things leads to performance, aka speed.

The times you start thinking of demoralization in the database, you usually do it in connection with pre-calculating results and queries and utilize caching so you don't have to do the joins on demand. So while there are some situations where de-normalization is a plausible solution - more often than not, you're still better off normalizing the data.

Comment: Moving to a design with such a flag does not affect normalization per se. The tables are different so queries & constraints are different for the same results & integrity. Eg a FK to a deleted-id table becomes a FK plus CHECK that the flag indicates deleted; but a query for deleted ids now needs no WHERE on the flag. Such change does not particularly affect normalization of the base tables. So "denormalized" is not the appropriate word/concept. It means something else. What you mean is "non-straightorward table meanings given the (subtype-supertype) distinctions important in this application".